# StackOverflowError: null error on play framework

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, stack-overflow

I am getting the error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[StackOverflowError: null]]
```

When I am running play app using the following command:

```
nohup ./target/universal/stage/bin/appName -Dhttp.port=9002 &
```

I can eliminate this error when running on IntelliJ using the parameter: -Xss2M

```
nohup ./target/universal/stage/bin/appName -Dhttp.port=9000 &
```

Is there anyway to root cause the issue, i.e. what is taking so much stack memory? Any pointer will be good.

I added this line also in build.sbt in root folder:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xss2M")
```

and then did:

```
sbt clean compile stage
```

then tried to run, but no success.
TIA

More info:

I was just trying to help myself, so tried investigating more, here is the infinite loop:

```
    studentMap.slice(1000,2000) = {StackOverflowError@12420} Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception.
  92 = {StackTraceElement@12516} "scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Stream.scala:237)"
  93 = {StackTraceElement@12517} "scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Stream.scala:237)"
  94 = {StackTraceElement@12518} "scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1085)"
  95 = {StackTraceElement@12519} "scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1077)"
  96 = {StackTraceElement@12520} "scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Stream.scala:237)"
  97 = {StackTraceElement@12521} "scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Stream.scala:237)"
  98 = {StackTraceElement@12522} "scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1085)"
```

Answer (score 0):

for linux:

```
./activator run -Dhttp.port=1234
```

the project is available on port 1234

I think have not use the activator.
If you download the play framework you will get the activator.
For creating a new project

```
./activator new [project name]
```

start the application

```
./activator run
```

If you want the production mode, then you have no help, type:

```
./activator run dist
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template probably have a tag which in turn have a reference to the initial root template, so you get infinite recursion and that error.